# How to clear memory from a qlikview document programmatically?

Tags: python, qlikview

I have lots of Qlikview documents in various folders. I would like to delete all the memory from all these documents programmatically , say for example using FOR LOOP in a python program. How can I do that? Are there other ways to do that?

Comment: By saying "all the memory" you mean all the data from the documents?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I want to delete all data from the qlikview file and only keep the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following visual basic script:

```
AppName = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)   
Set MyApp = CreateObject("QlikTech.QlikView")
Set MyDoc = MyApp.OpenDocEx(AppName, 0, False)
Set ActiveDocument = MyDoc 
MyDoc.RemoveAllData() 
MyDoc.SaveAs(AppName)  
MyDoc.CloseDoc() 
MyApp.Sleep 2000  
MyApp.Quit() 
Set MyDoc = Nothing 
Set MyApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if you can achieve this via Python. QlikView have a nice set of API but they are VBScript based.

An example macro that removes the data and saves the app:

```vb
sub RemoveData

    Set MyApp = CreateObject("QlikTech.QlikView")

    Set MyDoc = MyApp.OpenDocEx("c:\path\to\document.qvw",0,False)
    MyDoc.RemoveAllData
    MyDoc.SaveAs("c:\new\or\the\same\path.qvw")
    MyDoc.CloseDoc

    Set MyApp = Nothing

end sub
```

Check out the official [automation and macros](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview-developer/May2023/Subsystems/Automation/Content/QV_Automation/automation-introduction.htm) help page for more info

P.S. You can run these macros from within QlikView itself. Just press `Ctrl + m` to open the macro editor

P.S.1 There is QlikView COM API as well which can be called/used from VB.Net/C# but it requires a lot more setup compared to the macro approach